# linking a table with a list view icons

Tags: c#, listview, sql-server-2012

I'm working on a project that requires to link file i have uploaded to my DB with icons in the "listview" control in VS2013.and my database is sql server 2012
I Know how to access and get the specific column with select statement
by uisng the next classes

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
```

and i know how to add items into the "listview" control;
 i'm using large icon in the listview not the detaile one

```
listView1.Items.Add("test", 0);
```

but i don't know how to link each row with an icon.
please anybody can help??

Comment: What is your pattern?  Will the image always be the same for certain types, or will each item in the List be unique image?  Give us a model of the information, such as if Name is like '%Joe%', always show a Joe Boxer smiley face.  Something we can go off of.

Comment: yes the same pdf icon for all rows..because i have pdf files in the database and i want to display related icons for each file

Comment: let me get a mock up built and see if my idea of implementation will get what you need.  As well, will the path of the image be stored in the database, in the event that there is a different "logo" for the data item

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Display Data items and Details](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/display_data_items_and_details), with specific emphasis on the ItemTemplate section of the control building process.

[image]